# attribute (android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium") throws error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, attributes

why does this attribute throw error "Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextView"? my app crashed when i used the attribute to declare it to "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium", but when i changed it to hard-coded "16sp" it worked without crashing. what is wrong with this attribute?

```
<i>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:background="@color/tan_background"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwok_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            tools:text="lutti"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/default_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:text="one"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</i>
```

Comment: whats your attribute name? post ur xml

Comment: android:textSize = "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

Comment: Have you checked your res folder? Are such attributes defined there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
android:textSize=""?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium""
```

with this:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your `textSize` with `textAppearance`

**android:textAppearance**

> Base text color, typeface, size, and style.
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".

**textSize**

> Size of the text. Recommended dimension type for text is "sp" for
>   scaled-pixels (example: 15sp).
>
> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

Thats why your app gets crashed, hope it helps.